# Is it possible to use a dynamic query in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My aim is to get users that have id listed in an array.

EXAMPLE: 
I have an array of id's

`const usersId = [222, 444, 555, 522]`

and I want to get all users with those id's. each id is unique, meaning there can be only one user with that id.

I looked in the docs and from what I understood I need to handle this programmatically. So my only choice is to make a `get` request for each id?
this can be problematic because they can be more then a couple hundreds

this is my helper func:

```
export const getById = (id) => {

    db.collection('users')
        .where('id', '==', id)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        })
}
```

and this is a simplified example for the loop:

```
usersId.forEach(id => {
    getById(id);
})
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this can be problematic because they can be more then a couple hundreds

Actually as far as I understand it's not problematic. It's unintuitive, but by design you're supposed to make a bunch of requests like that because [Firebase actually pipelines all the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41573122/8237835), which makes it faster than you'd think.

If you use something like [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you should be able to better streamline your approach as well.

Comment: So by using promises with Firebase connection Im not sending a `http` request for each query?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Firebase doesn't use http requests but rather Websockets/long polling most likely. While http opens a connection, sends a request then closes it, firebase opens the connection then keeps it open.